# STM32 Input Capture Indirect Mode

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32

I am using STM32F446ZE Nucleo board. I wish to interface different sensors on the board, along with 5 encoders. However, using encoders with interrupts would be problematic as it would affect the operation of other parts and sensor readings. This application is highly time based. The encoders are to be read, but they aren't a priority. I wish to implement Input Capture mode along with Encoder mode, and would like to know what is Input Capture Indirect Mode, which isn't specified in datasheets and application notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input Capture Mode can be used to analyze signals by feeding them to Microcontroller. In STM32 Microcontrollers, they have provided with Input Capture Direct Mode & Input Capture Indirect Mode. These two mode only differ in how input is taken. After reading the [Timer Cookbook](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/91/01/84/3f/7c/67/41/3f/DM00236305/files/DM00236305.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00236305.pdf), TI1FP2 signals are fed to Channel 2 and TI2FP1 signals are fed to Channel 1. Similar can be said about Channel 3 and 4. (See attached image)

Further, I am adding the code snippet from HAL for STM32 Microcontrollers.

```
#define TIM_ICSELECTION_INDIRECTTI         (TIM_CCMR1_CC1S_1)   
/*!< TIM Input 1, 2, 3 or 4 is selected to be connected to IC2, IC1, IC4 or IC3, respectively */
```

Hence, Input Capture Indirect Mode can be used to feed signal to two channels internally.

Answer (score 2):

**Input Capture Mode** [[1]](https://letanphuc.net/2015/06/stm32f0-timer-tutorial-and-counter-tutorial/) is a method of dealing with input signals in embedded systems, which allows you to read a digital signal on a pin and measure times between HIGH and LOW transitions. This is useful for applications where the time "events" occurs is important.
In your particular STM32 board you can configure your timer to operate in input capture mode ([from man pages](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/54/0f/67/eb/47/34/45/40/DM00042534.pdf/files/DM00042534.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00042534.pdf)):

> The timer can be used in input capture mode to measure an external signal. Depending on timer clock, prescaler and timer resolution, the maximum measured period is deduced.
>   The input capture module is used to capture the value of the counter after a transition is detected by the corresponding input channel. To get the external signal period, two consecutive captures are needed. The period is calculated by subtracting these two values

I am not sure what STM means with **indirect mode**, and could not promptly find any directions in your board Timer Manual. I believe you will be better of asking in [STM forum](https://community.st.com/s/).

Comment: Reading the timer cookbook does help me understand the finer details of Input Capture Mode. I have used Input Capture Direct mode to get encoder signal pulses and calculated the speed. I am really confused about **bold** indirect mode.

Thanks for the answer!